# How to capture reject on Q.all() when querying mongoose?

Tags: promise, q, meanjs

I finally figured out how properly to use `Q.all()` in my code and it works as expected, but I don't know how to detect the reject if error comes from database in my specific code. I googled a lot but the problem is that in this particular case I can't relate the information I find by google to my own problem! Now with code, I have:

```
function username(user) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var queryu = User.find();
    queryu.where({_id: user});
    queryu.exec(function(err, results) {
        if (err) { //system level error
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else {
            var nameAndFB = extractinfo(results[0]);
            deferred.resolve(nameAndFB);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

later, I have another method that uses this one:

```
function masterUserObj(user, curstate) {
    var p1 = username(user);
    var p2 = getState(curstate);
    return Q.spread([p1, p2], function(userinfo, pairstate) {
        var obj1 = {};
        obj1.username = userinfo[0];
        obj1.fbid = userinfo[1];
        obj1.idprovider = userinfo[2];
        obj1.state = pairstate;
        return obj1;
    });
}
```

finally, a for loop puts all above to use:

```
function exposePairs(results, res) {
    var plist = [];
    for (var i = 0, m = results.length; i < m; i++) {
        plist[i] = masterUserObj(results[i].user, results[i].state);
    }
    Q.all(plist).then(function(theArr) {
        return res.jsonp({pairs: theArr});
    });
}
```

Code works, but I don't know where and how best to detect the reject case: deferred.reject(err);

Mainly I'm confused because I just learned to put promises in use together with a loop.

Please point me to the best practices.

**Edit:**
Also, please comment on code if I should use .done() after the final Q.all() or it is not necessary here.

Comment: Which information did you find with google that you cannot relate to your use case?

Comment: I found similar cases, for example q.all().then(function(data){},function(err){}) but I'm not sure what is the best practice in this case that I use both Q.spread() and then Q.all(). I just added the error catch method to my final Q.all() but also I don't know if something goes wrong in Q.spread() will that error get captured in Q.all() or not.

Comment: Yes, if one of the promises in `plist` (the ones created by `Q.spread`) fails, then the result promise `Q.all(plist)` will be immediately rejected and your error handler is called.

Comment: Thank you very much! Should I add a .done() to my Q.all() please? I didn't fully understand what the done() will do. My best guess is that it simply removes the promise at all i.e. works as a promise killer.

Comment: `.done()` is for crashing your app when you've made a mistake, instead of silently swallowing exceptions. IIRC, Q recommends it on the end of every promise chain.

Comment: I read the exact same thing in Q documentation, but this is first time I'm using Q at all. So in my particular code above, at least it should not harm if I add a .done() in my final Q.all(), do you agree please? or must add it to  Q.Spread() too?

Comment: No, the promise created by `Q.spread` in your usage is `return`ed from the function, and therefore not at the end of the chain. And yes, adding `.done` should not do harm.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm now full clear mind with it SO Cheer! :-)